# Computed mysql variables don't show up in PHP resultset

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the below query in `Sequel Pro`, I get results for all columns

```
select distinct
@company_id := a.company_id as company,
@current_date := max(stock_date) as currentdate, 
@other_date := date_sub(@current_date, interval 0 day) as other_date, 
@shares_bought := (select sum(volume) from my_portfolio where company_id=@company_id and posted_by = '5977479698B58' and trans_type='BUY') as shares_bought, 
@shares_sold := (select IF(sum(volume) IS NULL, 0, sum(volume)) from my_portfolio where company_id=@company_id and posted_by = '5977479698B58' and trans_type='SELL') as shares_sold, 
@shares_held := (@shares_bought-@shares_sold) as shares_held, 
@current_price := (select close from stock_prices where company_id=@company_id and stock_date <= @other_date order by stock_date desc limit 1) as current_price, 
(@current_price*@shares_held) as market_value 
from my_portfolio a 
inner join stock_prices b on a.company_id = b.company_id 
group by company
```

However, my PHP `var_dump()` shows null values for some of the columns that actually have values.

[Image: var_dump from PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSvwy.png)

[Image: results of the same query from Sequel Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK4lC.png)

Comment: run each of those child queries in your select clause individually and verify whether they are giving proper results.

Comment: The child queries are dependent on some of the user defined variables so technically won't 'work' individually unless I hardcode some values

Comment: show you php code

Comment: As SQL optimizers in general take the liberty to change execution order, i do not think it is a wise thing to assign variables, and depend on their values within a single query... Should try to re-word your query to not use variables...

Comment: What I am wondering though is why Sequel Pro and PhpMyadmin will show results but PHP wouldn’t show values for columns that actually have values.

Comment: There are only 2 columns that show `NULL` value in `PHP` that is not `NULL` on the other image: `other_date` and the dependent `market_value`... So why do you need this `other_date` column?

Comment: `other_date` lets you compute the price of a stock at the said date in the past. So the `@other_date` variable is actually  `@other_date := date_sub(@current_date, interval _ANY_NUMBER_OF_DAYS_ day) as other_date`

Answer (score 0):

If `other_date` is always the same as `currentdate` then try something like this:

```
SELECT company, currentdate, currentdate AS other_date, shares_bought, shares_sold,
       shares_held, current_price, current_price * shares_held AS market_value
FROM ( SELECT company, currentdate, currentdate AS other date, shares_bought, shares_sold,
              shares_bought - shares_sold AS shares_held, 
              ( SELECT close FROM stock_prices WHERE company_id = q.company_id
                   AND stock_date <= currentdate ORDER BY stock_date DESC
                LIMIT 1 ) AS current_price
       FROM ( SELECT a.company_id AS company, MAX(stock_date) AS currentdate,
                     COALESCE( SUM( b.volume ), 0 ) AS shares_bought,
                     COALESCE( SUM( s.volume ), 0 ) AS shares_sold
              FROM stock_prices a
              JOIN my_portfolio b ON b.company_id = a.company_id AND b.trans_type = 'BUY'
                                 AND b.posted_by = '5977479698B58'
              JOIN my_portfolio s ON s.company_id = a.company_id AND s.trans_type = 'SELL'
                                 AND s.posted_by = '5977479698B58'
              GROUP BY a.company_id
            ) q
     ) w
```

I was very tempted to use CTE (the `WITH` clause) but it is only usable with MySQL 8....

Comment: `other_date` is not always the same as `currentdate`.  The 0 in `date_sub(@current_date, interval 0 day)` is pulled in dynamically so could be any number between 0 and 366. Your approach though, has given me an idea. Trying...